# Finding a function from only knowing its derivative at a point.

Tags: calculus

This question on my last calc exam, I am told is very easy, but I do not understand how it is possible.

> $ \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\sqrt[3]{27+h}-3}{h}$ is the derivative of $f(x)$ at point $a$.
>
> Find $f(x)$ and find $a$.

I recognize the definition of the derivative.

Therefore I know that $f(a + h) = \sqrt[3]{27+h}$ and $f(a) = 3$

Then I am stuck.

What is this question asking? How can we know the integral (the entire function $f(x)$) from the derivative at a single point?

In lieu of an explanation I will accept an algorithm which I can use to solve it.

Comment: That question doesn't make much sense, unless it's some kind of trick question. Or did you mean to write $\lim_{h \to 0}$ rather than $\lim_{x \to 2}$?

Comment: Yes, I meant h->0 sorry.

Comment: Hint: what "action" are you doing at $f(a)?$

Comment: And on the left-hand side you meant $f'(a)$ rather than $f'(x)$, I suppose?

Comment: Actually the question doesn't specify if it is f(x) or f(a). I assumed it was f(x) from the wording

Comment: The phrase “the derivative of $f(x)$ at the point $a$” definitely specifies that it's $f'(a)$ and not $f'(x)$.

Comment: @Hans okay I edit the problem to correct my mistake.

Comment: Ben, it's just doing a little bit of comparison to the definition of derivative and what you have here to identify the function. There is no algorithm needed. The hint for the function is in the cube root part.

Comment: Also, be aware that there are infinitely many valid answers to this question. There won't be an algorithm that pinpoints one in particular!

Answer (score 2):

You don't know the function $f$ from the single derivative $f'(a)$. You know it from the expression $f(a+h)=\sqrt[3]{27+h}$, which holds for *all* $h$, so that you can simply substitute $h=x-a$ on both sides. The answer that you get will be valid for any number $a$ that you choose, so the question is somewhat strangely formulated ($a$ can be anything, i.e., it isn't at all determined by the given data).

Comment: +1 Not to mention, the limit given is a number. If I had set this question, and a student had simply written $f(x) = \left(\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\sqrt[3]{27 + h} - 3}{h}\right)x$ or (with $a$ being anything), then I'd feel compelled to give full marks and rethink that question in the future.

Comment: @TheoBendit: Haha, good point!

Comment: So if a = x, f(x) = 3? Is that a valid answer?

Comment: According to the professor there is one answer. $f(x) =  \sqrt[3]{x}$, and $a = 27$. Based on that answer, can anyone reword the question to properly fit the answer?

Comment: So ask your professor what's wrong with $f(x) = \sqrt[3]{x-1}$ and $a=28$. Or $f(x)=\sqrt[3]{27+x}$ and $a=0$. Or, for that matter, following Theo's suggestion: $f(x) = x/27$ and $a = 12345$ (since the given limit is actually equal to $1/27$)!

Comment: I should amend my statement. My professor provided one answer and did not state that there were any others. If I justified had my response as well as you guys, I'm sure I would have gotten full credit.